# SELECT on one TABLE with IF THEN

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I've got one table with addresses for contracts and customers.
Each address have one column which declare the addresstype (contract or customer)
and another column with the contract-number or with the customer-number

Now I want to select this table in the following way.
Query parameter are contract-Number and corresponding customer-number

If there are contract-addresses for a given contract-Number  then select them
if there are also for this contract-number and the corresponding customer-number
customer-addresses don't select them

If there are no contract-addresses for a given contract-Number then
select the customer-addresses for the corresponding customer-number.

I've no idea how to do that.
Possible?

BR
Eric

edit 2016/07/14:

Afterwards some clarification for the above described problem. 
Given is the following table

```
CustomerID  ObjectType  ObjectID    ADDR1   ADDR2   ADDR3 .....
10000       1           10000       ssdf    34543   dfgdf   
10000       1           10000       dfgg    kjh     jkhjkh
10000       2           23212       kljklj  lkjlkj  lkjlkj
10000       2           23213       kljklj  lkjlkj  lkjlkj
10001       1           10001       ssdf    34543   dfgdf   
10001       1           10001       dfgg    kjh     jkhjkh
10001       2           23212       kljklj  lkjlkj  lkjlkj
10001       2           23213       kljklj  lkjlkj  lkjlkj
10002       1           10001       ssdf    34543   dfgdf   
10002       1           10001       dfgg    kjh     jkhjkh
```

When I do a select on this table I want to have only the records with ObjectType=2 for each CustomerID.

If there are no recordsets with ObjectType=2 then the select must return all recordsets with ObjectType=1.

I hope now it is understandable.

For example:

- CustomerID=10000 should return 2 records for ObjectType=2
- CustomerID=10002 should return 2 records for ObjectType=1

BR 
Eric

Comment: it is for MSSQL-2012

Comment: Yes this is possible. If you want a more detailed response you need to provide more details. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: pls post relevant schemas

Answer (score 0):

--1. Create a quick temp table

```
  select CustomerID, max(ObjectType) into #MaxObjects from MyTable --Replace MyTable with whatever your table name is
```

--2. Inner join based on that table to your original.

```
select t1.* from MyTable as t1
```

inner join #MaxObjects as mo on t1.CustomerID =mo.CustomerID and t1.ObjectType = mo.ObjectType